# Pictogram Teaser

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, rebus

These guys wish they could have what they symbolize...

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe

> Cross-ant to Croissant

Because

> The ants want some tasty food.

Comment: WOW!  I'm impressed.  I thought that one would take folks a while.